# How to reference built-in C types with RST?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm documenting a C library with Sphinx and RST; I'm hoping to reference some of C's built-in types within the documentation for several functions. For example, I want to reference C's `double` type.

I do have at the very top of the file some config to make sure the domain is C:

```
.. default-domain:: c
.. highlight:: c
```

Referencing `` :type:`double` ``  or `` :c:type:`double` ``  within the function definitions does the job of formatting just fine, but I get a warning when building: `Unparseable C cross-reference: 'double'`. I gather this is because I haven't explicitly defined the type of `double` like so:

```
.. c:type:: double
```

But defining the type means that it will be visible -- and displaying the built-in types of C on my documentation is suboptimal.

Is there a way to use the `:type:` syntax within my documentation to reference C built-in types without defining them explicitly (or, if I must define them, to hide the definitions)? Or, alternately, is there a way to silence the build warning? Or, as a third option, is it probably just best to use the `:code:` syntax, and if so, is there a way to make its styling identical to that of the `:type:` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time you can not declare the built-in C types (at least it is not supposed to work). However, you can style them using the `:c:expr:` and `c:texpr:` roles (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#inline-expressions-and-types).